# Regular expression to recognize string of '#'

Tags: java, regex

I have a java question. I can't figure out how to write my regular expression to print something to a file when encountering one or more instances of '#'. It must not print when the `string equals` "", but it must print when the `string equals` "#". Here's my code:

```java
int num = 1;
StringBuffer noletterbuf = new StringBuffer(nospaces);
noletterbuf.deleteCharAt(0);
String noletter = noletterbuf.toString();
//if(num == noletter.split("[^#]").length){//applies # to C# and C
if(num == noletter.split("[#*]").length){//applies # to C
double yacc = octave*-50;
p6.println("sb.append(\"/Times-Roman findfont 70 scalefont setfont 1 -1 scale newpath  \"); sb.append(" + xaccplace + " + \" \" +" + yacc + " + \" moveto \"); sb.append(\"( # ) show 1 -1 scale \");");
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Bjorn

Answer (score 4):

Why use regex and `.split()` at all, since you just discard the resulting array?

You can check if the string contains `#` using the following:

```
if (noletter.indexOf('#') >= 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann Yup. But for one-character checks, I always use `indexOf()` as I believe it's faster.

Comment: @Eric: `contains` will just invoke `indexOf`. Any performance difference should be trivial/non-bottleneck.

Comment: @nhahtdh It may be a minimal impact, but `indexOf(char)` and `indexOf(String)` are not the same method. (They both have individual implementations.) It's just personal preference, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
noletter.split("[#*]")
```

This will split at each `#` and each `*`, since the asterisk is within brackets.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to check using regex is:

```
if (str.matches(".*#.*")) // true if there's a # in str
```

I don't understand the "no spaces" relevance, or why you used a StringBuffer, or why you deleted the first character.